# Calculate risk that occurs p% of a time

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, risk-assessment

In a search of a way to calculate variance for risk management I found the following formula
(n1, n2, n3 are data points):

```
avg = (n1+n2+n3)/3
variance = ((n1 - avg)^2 + (n2 - avg)^2 + (n3 - avg)^2) / (3-1)
```

Next, to calculate risk that occurs 5% of a time you do this:

```
risk5 = 1.65 * variance
```

And 1% of a time:

```
risk1 = 2.33 * variance
```

What interests me is how were these two values (1.65, 2.33) calculated. What is a general formula to find a risk that occurs p% of a time?

Comment: My first guess is that it comes from a student's t distribution. However, a 1 percent risk should have a larger multiple of the variance than a 5  percent risk--it is that much more unlikely. That is, for 1 percent, you want avg plus or minus risk1, for 5 percent, avg plus or minus risk5.

Comment: @Trurl: about risk1 vs risk5: you're right, that was an error in my typing (needed exchange in original post, now is corrected).